# Highlight PHP code in HTML with code tag - bug?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm using highlight.js to highlight the following code:

```
<pre><code class="hljs php">
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($keys as &$k)
    {
    echo '<th>'.$k.'</th>';
    }
 echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>'
</code></pre>
```

AAAnd all the table tags are rendered by the browser and not displayed as clear text...
[see for yourself(jsfiddle without highlight.js)](http://jsfiddle.net/ch4uc5z0/4/)

Is it me oris there something wrong with the code tags?
Any Ideas?
Thank you

Comment: the only thing wrong here is your [misunderstanding of the code tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code).

Comment: So its only 'style'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tags:

```
<pre><code bla bla> must end </pre></code>
```

Final

```
<pre><code bla bla> must end </code></pre>
```

**EDIT:**
Answer in the comments:

```
<pre>
    <code class="hljs php">
        &lt;table&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;th&gt;1&lt;/th&gt;
                &lt;th&gt;2&lt;/th&gt;
                &lt;th&gt;3&lt;/th&gt;
                &lt;th&gt;4&lt;/th&gt;
                &lt;th&gt;5&lt;/th&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;/table&gt;
    </code>
</pre>
```

Its nessecsary to HTML Escape the '<' and the '>'.
This can be achieved with [this php Function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Ok you have to change the '<' and '>' chars to his corresponding html code: http://jsfiddle.net/olliestrevel/dL7e41q6/

Comment: Thank you very much!! But shouldn't the code tag "deactivate" the (also html)code inside?

Comment: The code tag just highlight the text into the html tags inside, the mark up render normally

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the HTML5 tag  ?

```
<mark>Text here</mark>
```

Comment: well ... http://jsfiddle.net/9m3hsorp/ - but I understand now. Thx for your contribution!

Comment: Don't mark everything. Just the part you want marked.